# Unable to execute Invoke-Command from Azure DevOps pipeline (works fine locally)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, invoke-command, winrm

Something strange is happening with my PowerShell script.

1. I use Azure DevOps to automate a certain task, using YML pipelines.
2. I need to copy files from Azure DevOps repo to a remote machine, which is a VM on Azure (a DTL machine to be precise - shouldn't make a difference though)
3. Copying said files is done using the FTP task - it works so we know it's configured correctly.
4. After the files are copied over, I need to install an application there. Here's the strange behaviour:

I use the `PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3` task to run an *inline* script, according to which

a - It checks if the machine is connected to the DC (using `Test-ComputerSecureChannel`) - **that works**

b - Checks if a specific application is installed (like this: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "app*" }`) and if it is, uninstalls it (using the `uninstall()` method) - **that also works**

c - Installs the app from the directory that was copied over using the FTP task (using `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\<path_to_the_msi>.msi /qn" -Wait -NoNewWindow }` ) - this does not work!

But the real interesting thing is this: If I run the same script on the VM locally, it works - meaning *a* and *b* works as expected and *c* also works - it installs the application just fine.

Now I am sure you know how the `PowerShellOnTargetMachines` works, but in case you do not, it basically uses WinRM to *write* the inline script (that's in the task itself) into a temporary `ps1` file (at `$HOME\AppData\Local\Temp`) in the VM, and execute it. It is available there only for a brief period because it's deleted soon after, but I even went in there and opened the temp ps1 file copied the contents (which is same as my own script), and ran it AND THAT WORKED!

So the way I see it is that my code works because as per the inline script, tasks *a* and *b* do execute. It's just the *c* has an issue. And yes, I have tried `Start-Process` (like this: `Start-Process -FilePath C:\<pat_to_the_msi>.msi -ArgumentList "/quiet /passive"`) and that doesn't work either.

FYI: TrustedHost is set to "*".

So long story short, an inline PS script does not work from the pipeline, but does locally, essentially, with some caveats (that the script written into the `temp` location works and installs the application but doesn't allow PS to execute it).

Why am I using the FTP task to copy instead of `AzureFileCopy` is for another day - yes I am aware they both (`PowerShellOnTargetMachines` and `AzureFileCopy`) use WinRM.

Any help is immensely appreciated!